# Can I profile a normal/sequential (not parallelized) fortran .f90 file in PGI Visual Fortran 2015? I only have f90 files, no executables

Tags: fortran, profiler, pgi-visual-fortran

How can I profile a fortran .f90 file in PGI Visual Fortran 2015? I only have f90 files, no executables in my project.

Comment: You can't profile anything other than an executable.  As it stands your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "profile a fortran .f90 file".

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm new at this. So knowing that only executables can be profiled is something.
Vladimir, I have some f90 file with some numerical methods implemented and my (numerical) Simulation is running, I see the results displayed in the command line, but so far I don't generate any .exe
I Need to parallelize this code, so I want to Profile it first. I am not a programmer, just an applied mathematician, a Little rusty with Fortran, running some macroeconomic models that Need to be parallelized on GPUs. Thanks for any help and/or guidance.

Comment: I just solved the Problem, thanks Mark and Vladimir, I solved it by finding the exe from the Project :p 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/391828